# I keep getting error:40 when trying to save data entry into SQL database i created with the click of a button

Tags: vb.net, sqlconnection

I am pretty new to VB, and I have written a few lines of code but each time I run the program I keep getting

```
provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
```

, here is my lines of code

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnSave.Click
    Dim strConnection As String = "Data Source= (local);" & "DataBase='GUU_PATIENT_RECORDDataSet';" & "Integrated Security=yes;"
    Dim strTreatment_price As String = "INSERT INTO Treatment_price(Patient_Name, " & "Patient Address,Hospital_Number,Phone_Number, Admitted Date,Patients Date Of Birth,Blood Group,Genotype,Treatment1,Treatment2,Treatment3,Treatment4,Treatment5,Treatment6,Price_Unit1,Price_Unit2,Price_Unit3,Price_Unit4,Price_Unit5,Price_Unit6, " & "Sub_Total,VAT,Previous_BAl,NET_Total)" & _
    "VALUES ('" & Patient_NameTextBox.Text & "','" & Patient_AddressTextBox.Text & "','" & Hospital_NumberTextBox.Text & "','" & Phone_NumberTextBox.Text & "','" & Blood_Group_TextBox.Text & "','" & GenotypeTextBox.Text & "','" & Treatment1TextBox.Text & "','" & Treatment2TextBox.Text & "','" & Treatment4TextBox.Text & "','" & Treatment5TextBox.Text & "','" & Treatment6TextBox.Text & "','" & Price_Unit1TextBox.Text & "','" & Price_Unit2TextBox.Text & "','" & Price_Unit3TextBox.Text & "','" & Price_Unit4TextBox.Text & "','" & Price_Unit5TextBox.Text & "','" & Price_Unit6TextBox.Text & "','" & Sub_TotalTextBox.Text & "','" & VATTextBox.Text & "','" & Previous_BalTextBox.Text & "','" & Net_TotalTextBox.Text & "');"

    Using connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(strConnection)
        Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(strTreatment_price, connection)
        Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Patient_Payment_info", connection)
        Dim ds As GUU_PATIENT_RECORDDataSet = New GUU_PATIENT_RECORDDataSet
        da.Fill(ds.Patient_Payment_Info)
        Patient_Payment_InfoDataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        connection.Open()
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Record Successfully Validated.")
    End Using
```

Comment: That is not the correct way to create SQL statements.  A minimum amount of research here will show how and why you should use SQL Parameters

Comment: Lot of problems here: 1) Fields with spaces need to be enclosed in square brackets _[Patient Address]_ 2) AVOID absolutely string concatenations and use instead Parameterized Queries 3) Insert Into statement are executed using an SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery method.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps.

```
1. Open control panel.
2. Search for services.
3. Open Local services window from the search results
4. Restart the MSSQLSERVER service.
```

Comment: okay thanks, but can youn give me an idea of how to parameterize ?